# How to start primary key from 0 while importing

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, primary-key

I tried to import `csv` file to `Mysql`. The `ID` id starts from `0`. It showing `duplicate entry`, while importing. Is there any solution to do it?

my migration file is

```
class CreateActors < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :actors  do |t|
      t.string :title 
      t.float :rating
      t.string :place
      t.string :address
      t.string :special
      t.string :amount
      t.string :phone
    end
   end
end
```

`id` is taken as primary key by default

My csv file shown as

```
id   title  rating   place   address   amount   phone
0     .       .       .       .         .        .    
1     .       .       .       .         .        .
```

while importing this, I got this error

```
 ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: If the file has duplicate values, you need to import to a staging table. Remove duplicates and then add to main table

Comment: it's primary key, while starting it from 0. It showing duplicate entry

Comment: Could you please tell us how the primary key is defined?, are there already entries on the table? example of your primary-keys?

Comment: the id is the primary key and it's starts from 0 and end at 30. It consist of 31 entries.

Comment: And the table is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys usually are set by the database system and are `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

I see several solutions here:

- If you need to keep that ID from the file, just add another field to the table and put that value there, while letting the DB set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.
- Forget about the AUTO_INCREMENT and have a `File_ID` and a `Row_ID` which together compose a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key. Set the `File_ID` according to an additional table which keeps record of the files which have been imported.

Comment: Is it possible to place 0 value in the primary key?

Comment: @users4393829 AFAIK yes.